# Apex Test Class Code Coverage Failure

Tags: apex, visualforce, trigger, unit-test

This is the Trigger that I am trying to get code coverage for, but my test class is failing.Both testMethods are passing, but it's saying "No Code Coverage". So I guess my two test methods aren't really testing anything? Can someone help explain where I am going wrong, or what I am missing? Thanks!

**Trigger**

```
    trigger FinanceApprovalAdDirector on Rate_Request__c (before insert,before update) {
    for(Rate_Request__c fa: trigger.new)
    {
        Market__c m = [Select Ad_Director__c From Market__c WHERE Unit_Number__c = :fa.Owner_Market__c];
        fa.Ad_Director__c = m.Ad_Director__c;
        User u = [Select ManagerId From User WHERE Id = :UserInfo.getUserId()];
        fa.Manager__c = u.ManagerId;
    }
}
```

**My Test Class**

```
@isTest(SeeAllData=true)
public class FinanceApprovalAdDirectorTest{
 static testMethod void testRateRequestManager(){
        Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='Standard User'];
        User u1 = new User(Alias = 'standt1', Email='standarduser1@testorg.com', EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', LastName='Testing', LanguageLocaleKey='en_US', LocaleSidKey='en_US', ProfileId = p.Id, TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles', UserName='standarduser43431212@testorg.com');      
        User u = new User(Alias = 'standt', Email='standarduser@testorg.com', EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', LastName='Testing', LanguageLocaleKey='en_US', LocaleSidKey='en_US', ProfileId = p.Id, TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles', UserName='standarduser@43431313testorg.com', ManagerId = u1.id);      

        System.runAs(u){
            Market__c m = new Market__c();
            m.Unit_Number__c = '1111';
            m.Name = 'test';
            m.Ad_Director__c = u.id;
            insert m;

            Market__c mTest = [SELECT Ad_Director__c, Unit_Number__c, Name FROM Market__c WHERE Unit_Number__c = :m.Unit_Number__c];

            test.startTest();
            Rate_Request__c rr = new Rate_Request__c();
            rr.Ad_Director__c = mTest.Ad_Director__c;
            rr.Manager__c = u.ManagerId;

            System.assertEquals(u1.id, rr.Manager__c);
            System.assertNotEquals(u.id, rr.Manager__c);
            test.stopTest();
        }
    }

    static testMethod void testRateRequestAdDirector(){
        Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='Standard User'];
        User u = new User(Alias = 'standt1', Email='standarduser1@testorg.com', EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', LastName='Testing', LanguageLocaleKey='en_US', LocaleSidKey='en_US', ProfileId = p.Id, TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles', UserName='standarduser13131212@testorg.com');      
        User u1 = new User(Alias = 'standt', Email='standarduser@testorg.com', EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', LastName='Testing', LanguageLocaleKey='en_US', LocaleSidKey='en_US', ProfileId = p.Id, TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles', UserName='standarduser@12121313testorg.com', ManagerId = u.id);      

        System.runAs(u){
            Market__c m = new Market__c();
            m.Unit_Number__c = '1111';
            m.Name = 'test';
            m.Ad_Director__c = u.id;
            insert m;

            Market__c mTest = [SELECT Ad_Director__c, Unit_Number__c, Name FROM Market__c WHERE Unit_Number__c = :m.Unit_Number__c];

            test.startTest();
            Rate_Request__c rr = new Rate_Request__c();
            rr.Ad_Director__c = mTest.Ad_Director__c;

            System.assertEquals(u.id, rr.Ad_Director__c);
            System.assertNotEquals(u1.id, rr.Ad_Director__c);
            test.stopTest();
        }     
    }    

}
```

Comment: It would speed up a proper answer being generated if you would define specifically wha you mean by "failing" (which assert, error, etc)

Comment: Both testMethods are passing, but it's saying "No Code Coverage". So I guess my two test methods aren't really testing anything?

Comment: See updated answer

Comment: In additon to the excellent answers below ... Best Practice says get rid of `SeeAllData=true` - mock all data needed by testmethods. `SeeAllData=true` can lead to failed deployments now or in the future

Answer (score 1):

First Mistake:

> You should never have a SOQL query inside for loop.

Before moving to your test classes, replace your code with this

```
Map<ID,List<String>> markerOwnerList = new Map<ID,List<String>>();
for(Rate_Request__c fa: trigger.new){
    if(markerOwnerList.containsKey(fa.Owner_Market__c))
        markerOwnerList.get(fa.Owner_Market__c).add(fa.id);
    else
        markerOwnerList.put(fa.Owner_Market__c,new List<String>{fa.id});
}

Map<ID,String> rrDirectorMap = new Map<ID,String>();

for(Market__c m : [Select Ad_Director__c,Unit_Number__c From Market__c WHERE Unit_Number__c = :markerOwnerList.keySet()]){
    for(String rateRequest : markerOwnerList.get(m.Unit_Number__c))
        rrDirectorMap.put(rateRequest,m.Ad_Director__c);
}

User u = [Select ManagerId From User WHERE Id = :UserInfo.getUserId()];
for(Rate_Request__c fa: trigger.new){
    if(rrDirectorMap.containsKey(fa.id))
        fa.Ad_Director__c = rrDirectorMap.get(fa.id);

    fa.Manager__c = u.ManagerId;
}
```

Regarding your test class, you are not inserting the RateRequest record after creating it.

```
@isTest(SeeAllData=true)
public class FinanceApprovalAdDirectorTest{
 static testMethod void testRateRequestManager(){
        Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='Standard User'];
        User u1 = new User(Alias = 'standt1', Email='standarduser1@testorg.com', EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', LastName='Testing', LanguageLocaleKey='en_US', LocaleSidKey='en_US', ProfileId = p.Id, TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles', UserName='standarduser43431212@testorg.com');      
        User u = new User(Alias = 'standt', Email='standarduser@testorg.com', EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', LastName='Testing', LanguageLocaleKey='en_US', LocaleSidKey='en_US', ProfileId = p.Id, TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles', UserName='standarduser@43431313testorg.com', ManagerId = u1.id);      

        System.runAs(u){
            Market__c m = new Market__c();
            m.Unit_Number__c = '1111';
            m.Name = 'test';
            m.Ad_Director__c = u.id;
            insert m;

            Market__c mTest = [SELECT Ad_Director__c, Unit_Number__c, Name FROM Market__c WHERE Unit_Number__c = :m.Unit_Number__c];

            test.startTest();

            Rate_Request__c rr = new Rate_Request__c();
            insert rr;

            System.assertEquals(u1.id, rr.Manager__c);
            System.assertNotEquals(u.id, rr.Manager__c);
            test.stopTest();
        }
    }
}
```

I hope you will be able to fix your next method.

Comment: The trigger is only looping through one Rate Request at a time, so shouldn't it be fine in this case? I know the rule that its not good practice in most cases, but this one shouldn't be an issue I believe

Comment: @Stephen No. If you end up with 51 `Rate_Request__c` objects that get updated in a single shot, you'll run into the soql query limit with your current trigger. Even if you don't think you'll run into that situation, it's a very good idea to plan for it. You'd also run into this issue as your code base expands, and more things start interacting with `Rate_Request__c`

Comment: @Stephen - No, never get into the habit of doing this even if you think the trigger will only process a single record in a transaction. You need to heed this advice or you are starting from a point of failure that will come back to bite you as your code expands and requirements change

Answer (score 0):

First Issue:

You are not Inserting the Rate_Request__c records so the trigger will never execute.

```
trigger FinanceApprovalAdDirector on Rate_Request__c (before insert,before update)
```

Since the trigger happens on insert or update it will not run unless you insert or update the appropriate records.

Once you do that this will happen

Your query:

```
[Select Ad_Director__c From Market__c WHERE Unit_Number__c = :fa.Owner_Market__c];
        fa.Ad_Director__c = m.Ad_Director__c;
```

requires that the `Rate_Request__c.Owner_Market__c` match the `Unit_Number__c`.

I do not see in your tests where you are setting the value of the Rate_Request__c.Owner_Market__c` thus it is null and does not match the value or the Unit_number__c and thus will return no results

This will result in a **List has no rows for assignment to sObject** error

Comment: It's saying that the field Rate_Request__c.Owner_Market__c is not writeable. How would you recommend getting the field to match the Market__C.Unit_Number__c without getting this error message?

Comment: Ok, I had no way of knowing it was a formula field. Where is that field pulling the data from? That is what you need to set.